# Transfer blob Image between mysql database and HTML using AJAX and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

My problem is not being able to encode the image properly after retrieving it from the database otherwise all my work is fine. After I fetch the image I managed to display it at the same php file using "header('content-type: image/jpeg')".

```
<?php

header('content-type: image/jpeg');
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $sql = "select image from images order by id desc limit 1";
 require_once('connection.php');

 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $result = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
 echo base64_decode($result['image']);
 mysqli_close($con);

 }else{
 echo "Error";
 }
?>
```

The previous piece of code is for displaying directly but it was for testing only, I need to use it as a JSON source so I modified it in this way:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
.
.
.
$r['a'] = base64_encode( $result['image']);
echo json_encode($r);
```

For the Jquery and Ajax part also worked fine and I tested it by making another json file and put an image encoded professionally by this website https://www.base64-image.de/.

And here is Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        (function() 
        {
        d='';       
        var poll=function()
           {
         $.ajax({
                url: "getjson.php",
                type :"get",
                dataType: "JSON",

                success: function(json)
                {
                   d +='data:image/jpeg;base64,';
                   d +=json.a;  
                  $("#myimg2").attr("src",d);
                }

               })

                };
              poll();

               setInterval(function(){
                  poll(); 
               }, 2000);
            })();   

            });
```

What I need now is to encode the image just like what this website does   https://www.base64-image.de/ because this line  `base64_encode( $result['image'])` seems to be not enough, I have tried many solutions available online but no one worked for me!